Why does the list.files() function return files that can not be found?
I am trying to use the base R function list.files() to return a list of file names (.txt files) so that I can import them in an automated way instead of writing a read.table() line per file.
Here is the problem that I'm encountering:
Using the list.files() function, I get the following output:
> list.files(pattern = "\\.txt$")
[1] "~$ DD - maskedfiletitle.txt"                   
[2] "~$ KP - maskedfiletitle.txt"
[3] "TF DD - maskedfiletitle.txt"                   
[4] "TL XF - maskedfiletitle.txt"                             
[5] "UR FG - maskedfiletitle.txt"                         
[6] "VB PD - maskedfiletitle.txt"                
[7] "VS KP - maskedfiletitle.txt"

The desired output is the following:
[1] "TF DD - maskedfiletitle.txt"                   
[2] "TL XF - maskedfiletitle.txt"                             
[3] "UR FG - maskedfiletitle.txt"                         
[4] "VB PD - maskedfiletitle.txt"                
[5] "VS KP - maskedfiletitle.txt"

It seems to always return the first and last file in the folder with the first two characters replaced by "~$". Obviously, if the next step is to read these files it will give an error message saying that the "~$" file does not exist.
For now I have worked around this by simply removing the first two elements. However, I have no answer as to why this behaviour occurs.
I have tried removing all non .txt files from the folder and rewriting the function to use different arguments:
> list.files(all.files = FALSE, no.. = TRUE)
[1] "~$ DD - maskedfiletitle.txt"                   
[2] "~$ KP - maskedfiletitle.txt"
[3] "TF DD - maskedfiletitle.txt"                   
[4] "TL XF - maskedfiletitle.txt"                             
[5] "UR FG - maskedfiletitle.txt"                         
[6] "VB PD - maskedfiletitle.txt"                
[7] "VS KP - maskedfiletitle.txt"

This, however, also gives me the first and last file with the first two characters changed to "~$".
Now, it's not a critical error or anything, but I'm interested in learning where this behaviour comes from. I have read through the help section of the function and I've searched a bit on the web but I cannot find anything that explains it and I am quite stumped.
Do let me know if I need to provide more information!

Usually any file that starts with ~$ is a temporary file. Are any of your .txt files currently open? Try closing them first. You can also supply a regular expression to the pattern argument to exclude files that start with ~$.

@nrennie please post as an answer with regex pattern.

@nrennie:  that's a good guess.  It's worth pointing out that the ~$ prefix is just a convention used by some software; other editors use other prefixes.  For example I see .~lock. as the prefix on files opened by Libreoffice.

Do you really get an error that says the files do not exist? I'm pretty sure list.files isn't lying, they are actually there, they just probably don't contain what you want.

@nrennie is correct, I was unaware that this is how open files are returned. Due to a conversion process outside of Rstudio (which leaves the first and final files opened) I wrongly concluded that this was buggy behaviour from list.files

Usually any file that starts with ~$ is a temporary file (at least on Windows). If any of your .txt files are currently open, try closing them first.
Otherwise, I thought you might be able to combine the files that end with .txt and files that don't start with ~$ conditions into one regex to use in the pattern argument (using "^(?!~\\$).*\\.txt$"). However, the pattern argument in list.files doesn't support negative lookahead directly, so you need to do it in two steps:

find all files that end with .txt (as you've already done)
then filter to exclude ones that start with ~$

my_files <- list.files(pattern = "\\.txt$")
txt_files <- my_files[!grepl("^~\\$", my_files)]


One comment:  if some of your files are open in an editor, it's not clear that you want to proceed at all.  Maybe you should abort the process right away, in case the version that's on the disk is missing some of the updates that are in the editor's copy.

Choosing this as the answer to the question since @nrennie was the first to mention that ~$ is added to temporary files. If you could add one sentence in the beginning of the answer that you should close all files you want to return with list.files,  then the answer is perfect. For my personal workflow I do appreciate having an extra regex line for now.

~$is used to prefix hidden temporary files that are created when a document is opened in Windows. You can filter them out by defining the pattern with Regular Expressions in R. Like:
filtered_files <- files[!grepl("^~\\$", files)]

It keeps the files that do not start with ~$

Here is how to use list.files() to select only the text files in your current working directory:
txt_files <- list.files(pattern = "*.txt")

my_files <- lapply(txt_files,readLines)

# assign files to variables
TF_DD <- my_files[[1]]
TL_XF <- my_files[[2]]
UR_FG <- my_files[[3]]
VB_PD <- my_files[[4]]
VS_KP <- my_files[[5]]

I hope it helps!

Note that the pattern= for list.files is a regular expression, not a file glob. Technically this would match a file named atxt.pdf as well.
